# How to stop Logback logging exceptions with a time prefix on each line?

Tags: java, logging, logback

This is the Logback stacktrace of an exception:

```
15:32:04.773 [localhost:9080] [UNKNOWN] [Unauthenticated] [0AE48E3EEF47ED3210CC45C3E20D273D] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-4 << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
15:32:04.773 [localhost:9080] [UNKNOWN] [Unauthenticated] [0AE48E3EEF47ED3210CC45C3E20D273D] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-4 << "[\r][\n]"
15:32:04.773 [localhost:9080] [UNKNOWN] [Unauthenticated] [0AE48E3EEF47ED3210CC45C3E20D273D] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-4 << "10e[\r][\n]"
15:32:04.773 [localhost:9080] [UNKNOWN] [Unauthenticated] [0AE48E3EEF47ED3210CC45C3E20D273D] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-4 << "<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Body><env:Fault><env:Code><env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value></env:Code><env:Reason><env:Text xml:lang="en-US">Internal Error (from client)</env:Text></env:Reason></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
15:32:04.773 [localhost:9080] [UNKNOWN] [Unauthenticated] [0AE48E3EEF47ED3210CC45C3E20D273D] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-4 << "0[\r][\n]"
```

My question is: **How to stop Logback logging exceptions with a time prefix on each line?** Is it a xml change or a change to the Java code?

EDIT: Clarification

I'm happy with the time prefix in general. The issue here is that some information is coming back and it is being split across multiple lines, and each line is prefixed with the time, which makes interpreting the original information even harder. What I want is the time on the first line, and the rest of the stack trace on the remaining lines.

This is the error I'm trying to see:

```
<env:Text xml:lang="en-US">Internal Error (from client)</env:Text>
```

Comment: Could be configured in a few different places, according to the [Logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html). Do you have any configuration files for it right now that sets the pattern?

Comment: There's no exception in your current log dump...